# JMenuBar causes content pane to repaint incorrectly

Tags: java, swing

I've encountered a very strange issue using JMenuBar where navigating between two JMenus results in the contentPane of the JFrame which the menu belongs to to repaint incorrectly. The content pane presents the correct background only where the menu items drop down and 'dirty' the screen -- the rest is entirely white. However, this only occurs after browsing between the two menus, and not right away. It takes a few seconds of switching between for the empty contentPane to change from the ordinary background color.

**EDIT** To clarify, this is on Windows 7 using JDK 1.7.0.

To better illustrate what I mean, here is the window after launch (manually resized):
[image: The window upon launch]

And then after using the JMenus for a few seconds:
[image: The content pane is now incorrectly painted]

Below is a **SSCCE** demonstrating the problematic code.

```
package com.test.workspace;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MenuBarTest extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Eclipse-generated SUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8836700685077107497L;

    public MenuBarTest() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu testMenu = new JMenu("Test");
        JMenuItem testItem = new JMenuItem("TestItem");

        JMenu breakMenu = new JMenu("Break");
        JMenuItem breakItem = new JMenuItem("BreakItem");

        testMenu.add(testItem);

        breakMenu.add(breakItem);

        menuBar.add(testMenu);
        menuBar.add(breakMenu);

        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MenuBarTest test = new MenuBarTest();
                test.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                test.pack();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems using JDK6_7 on XP.

Comment: No artifact on Mac OS X. Any chance the content pane's [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) is not being honored?

Comment: @trashgod I thought about opacity, but setting `setOpaque(true)` had no effect for me so I left it out of the SSCCE. I'm starting to wonder if it is indeed a platform-specific bug -- next step is for me to check it on a different OS or JDK.

Comment: What happens when you give the JFrame some content?

Comment: Adding a `JLabel` to the frame prevents the issue from occurring. At this point I suppose it must be a relatively minor platform-specific bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a platform-specific thing. The GUI appeared fine on my machine: Ubuntu 11.10, Eclipse 3.7, Sun JDK 7.

Comment: After posting this, I had a nagging doubt that it might be JDK1.7 related, but now I'm even more lost. Time to try it on XP or with JDK1.6 I guess.